# Android: Floating Button Icon is not centred

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm trying to create a floating button in my app. The button is there, but the image in the button is a bit upwards (see image).

[image]

I can't figure out what's wrong with it. Below is part of the XML for floating button.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="480dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_back_to_top_3x"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_light"
        app:fabSize="normal" />
```

The button is showing where I wanted it. The only problem seems to be the image inside isn't center. Why is this happening?

**EDIT**:
After some more looking around I realized the image itself was having problem where the image isn't actually centered and there are space at the bottom side (which cause the image to being push upward).

Comment: @Charuka yes, that was the correct reason, sorry I didn't check it just now. Was busy with some sudden issue. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason is your image is not in the right size!!

Floating action button default circle size is   56 x 56dp
,
to get the best fit use that for your background image!!

If you are going for a mini one should be : 40 x 40dp

If you only want to change the Interior icon(only icon) use a 24 x 24dp icon for default size

To test this again i download an image form internet and scaled it down to 56dp and kept a small space to balance it (i am no good with Photoshop)

[image]

and added this to your FB view and made background yellow to make it clear.Let's see

out put:

[image]

This means it depends on the image that you add and its size if you want to go full background you can even use an `imageButton`

Refer : https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button

Comment: Hey, could you please not delete your original answer and copy the answer below? Thank you.

Comment: @Demindiro Rollback the edit or flag it for a moderator to do so.

Answer (score 142):

I have faced the same problem. the following solution have worked for me

```
app:fabCustomSize="40dp"
```

Comment: `app:fabCustomSize` value should not always be 40dp. Depends on each view I had to use 50dp

Answer (score 53):

You should set fabCustomSize value like FAB exactly size:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:fabCustomSize="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/plus_icon"
        app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
```

Comment: Thank you! Why is this necessary?

Answer (score 6):

I just set the app:fabCustomSize=”40dp” (needed size) and I set the height and width as wrap_content then issue solved

Answer (score 4):

In addition to above answers, Whatever size you set for FAB, set same to **fabCustomSize**

for example, if width and height are "48dp" then set fabCustomSize to "48dp":

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back"
    app:fabCustomSize="48dp" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add only `app:fabCustomSize="40dp"`  it's work for me

Comment: `app:fabCustomSize="40dp"` worked for me as well. Thanks stackoverflow community.

Comment: This is exactly like the second answer, how is this different or helpful?

Answer (score 3):

**Here it is about setting three options together to adjust the navigation button with icon size**

1. layout width & height.
2. change icon size inside the nav.Button ~ Using (maxImageSize="..dp").
3. change fab size ~ Using (app:fabCustomSize="..dp") OR (app:fabSize="") You can try three options here ("mini" or "auto" or "normal").
   ***For example:***

   ```
   <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    app:maxImageSize="20dp"
    app:fabSize="mini"/>
   ```

Comment: using just the maxImageSize=25dp worked for me. Thanks @bola gamal

Answer (score 1):

Try to do to fix your height and width...

```
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
```

and please adjust your layout in bottom another way ..bacause here yo do

```
 android:layout_marginTop="480dp"
```

it is not a proper way my suggestion try to set your FloatingActionButton inside Relative Layout..and set like this property..

```
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

Comment: and why not android:layout_marginBottom? Don't you think a marginTop will create problems on different screens?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've found the issue (turns out it was the image problem of not centred and there's some space at the bottom side, can't believe I failed to noticed it). But thanks for the layout suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This usually arises when using custom-sized floating action button(FAB), because android by default, only supports 40dp FAB. The best way is to override it, by telling your view that you are using a custom sized FAB, and give the same size as value to it too.

For example, while using a 60dp x 60dp FAB, this will do the trick.

`app:fabCustomSize="60dp"`

Answer (score 0):

Use (https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button) and set fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_fab_star" to center icon

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is not to hardcode the FAB's dimension.

Icon will be centered with attribute `android:scaleType="center"`

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/search_fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/fab_search_icon"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:elevation="4dp"
                app:fabSize="normal"/>
```

Comment: This not worked.. Setting app:fabCustomSize="40dp" is my solution

Comment: @mDonmez that's good for you. 
You can check the code as well in edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Use layout width and height of floatingActionButton as wrap-content. It will solve all the problems .

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/iconPath"
    app:fabCustomSize="50dp"
     />
```

Customize size as you want.

Answer (score 0):

here is my custom fab :
fabCustomSize, layout_width, layout_height must be equal

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_reward"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/fab_reward"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/red4"
        app:fabCustomSize="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:maxImageSize="40dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_reward"
        app:tint="@null" />
```