# Floating Action Button Icon not centered inside

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to use a FAB but the icon inside is placing at bottom right of the button:

[FAB with icon not centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtsH1.png)

This is the FAB definition in the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/centerLocationButton"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/pro_arriving_map_location_button_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_my_location"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            app:fabSize="mini" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show you `@drawable/ic_my_location`

Comment: it is about your image using in FAB src
this answer may helpful :
[Fab icon not centered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41477457/8621930)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Floating Button Icon is not centred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477028/android-floating-button-icon-is-not-centred)

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59455009/3974530

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be a bug in the Design Support Library v28.0.0.

I could workarround this by setting the scaleType programmatically.

In your case in the Java/Kotlin Code:

```
centerLocationButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER)
```

Comment: Yeap, I ended up doing the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

My solution is `app:fabCustomSize="56dp"`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using material design and using custom sizes:

```
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

The fix is to use these two properties

```
app:fabCustomSize="80dp"
app:maxImageSize="70dp"
```

**make sure of this**

```
app:fabCustomSize = the same size as your layout_width
app:maxImageSize= about 10dp minus the size of your layout_width
```

Answer (score 1):

In my situation run ok this solution
`app:fab_icon="@drawable/btn_back_to_top_3x"`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6C1Q.png)
not
`android:src="@drawable/btn_back_to_top_3x`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbg8J.png)

And you can add
`android:scaleY="1.X"
 android:scaleX="1.X"`

for additional variation

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `android:src` try `app:srcCompat`. Is FAB only thing you are using, because if it is (judging by the pic you posted), maybe you don't need RelativeLayout as a parent, you can use `android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"`

Answer (score 0):

After updating to SDK 28, I've got the same problem. Changing the size, scaleType, layout_gravity, etc will return the same.

My current short-term solution is using the ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
android:width="wrap_content"
android:height="wrap_content"
app:maxImageSize ="56dp"
```

on the fab. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Please try given solution. It works for me.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:contentDescription="Chat"
        app:fabCustomSize="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/chat"
        app:borderWidth="1dp"
        app:useCompatPadding="true" />
```

Comment: where solution?