# Floating Action Button icon not in the center

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, floating-action-button

None of the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52635233/floating-action-button-icon-not-centered-inside) on SO helped me.

Here is my FAB xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fabTransfer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/fab_size_normal"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />
```

Here is the icon xml:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
 </vector>
```

And yet my icon looks like this!

[image]

Any ideas what's going on? I have tried with other icons too (pngs and vectors) and it's still the same.

Comment: Hopefully the vector tag is closed on your actual resource file and it was just omitted here by mistake

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Yeah it just got left out here for some reason

Comment: I'm wondering whether it has anything to do with the viewport which is essentially the size of teh canvas for the drawable. Try experimenting with the values and see if it makes any difference, or remove them altogether and see if that works.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I tried fiddling with the values but it always seems to be off centered, almost like its top-left is anchored in the wrong place

Comment: the only potential workaround I can think of is having an image asset as drawable instead of a vector one, and on the design tab of your layout drag the action button from the selection menu that android studio provides so you can see the wizard to guide you through applying a drawable on the foreground of your fab.

Comment: Hi Speed what is the version of com.google.android.material:material? Try to use 1.0.0

Comment: @AamirKhan Yup `'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` :(

Comment: can i have your xml file?

Comment: That's it, but with an `<xml ...>` at the start. Then it's included in a bunch of different layouts and it's the same in them all. LinearLayout, CoordinatorLayout, Framelayout, it's the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a style to the FAB which extends `Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton`

```
<style name="MyFabStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/fab_background</item>
        <item name="rippleColor">#0d9bed</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me and I don't see how the center align of the icon is affected by this custom style.

Comment: This worked however trying all the other proposed answers : fabTransfer.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER) I was migrating from the old support lib to 28+

Answer (score 10):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54035571/172690) you should try setting `app:fabCustomSize` to `24dp` and see if it works better.

Answer (score 0):

```
app:fabCustomSize="48dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

This could happen because the layout style is overriding the floating button style. To solve it make sure to reestablish the style defined as your own like this:

In *styles.xml*

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black_app</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="floatingActionButtonStyle">@style/FabButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FabButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="tint">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

And then making sure that the layout of the view complies with the style:

In *AndroidManifiest.xml*

```
<activity
            android:name=".OnBoardingActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" />
```

Answer (score -1):

try to change this property android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" to android:layout_gravity="center"

Comment: that shouldn't affect the drawable but the position of the entire button within its parent layout

Answer (score -1):

It is because you wrote :   android:layout_gravity="bottom|end", so it goes at bottom in the end.

You should replace it by "center"

If it doesn't work, try simply :

android:gravity="center"

Comment: Nope, layout_gravity affects a widget's position in the layout. android:gravity makes no difference here