# Floating action button not showing vector asset

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm trying to setup a vector asset into a fab. But the result is like this:
[image]
As you can see the vector is there but way down and to the left. here is the layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBg"
    tools:context=".ui.main.fragments.HomeFragment">


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_new_sale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cart_plus"
        android:scaleType="center"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_home_cards"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And heres is the vector:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:viewportWidth="200"
    android:viewportHeight="200">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M165.1,119.28L75,119.28l2,9.84h82.48a7.37,7.37 0,0 1,7.19 9l-1.7,7.46a17.2,17.2 0,1 1,-19.54 3.19L81,148.77a17.21,17.21 0,1 1,-20.6 -2.63L38.85,40.62L17.38,40.62A7.38,7.38 0,0 1,10 33.24L10,28.33A7.37,7.37 0,0 1,17.38 21h31.5a7.38,7.38 0,0 1,7.23 5.9l2.81,13.77h120.7a7.37,7.37 0,0 1,7.19 9l-14.52,63.91A7.38,7.38 0,0 1,165.1 119.28ZM135.38,72.58L120.63,72.58L120.63,60.28a4.92,4.92 0,0 0,-4.92 -4.91h-4.92a4.91,4.91 0,0 0,-4.91 4.91v12.3L91.13,72.58a4.91,4.91 0,0 0,-4.92 4.91v4.92a4.92,4.92 0,0 0,4.92 4.92h14.75L105.88,99.62a4.91,4.91 0,0 0,4.91 4.91h4.92a4.92,4.92 0,0 0,4.92 -4.91L120.63,87.33h14.75a4.92,4.92 0,0 0,4.91 -4.92L140.29,77.49A4.91,4.91 0,0 0,135.38 72.58Z" />
</vector>
```

I will appreciate any help with this issue

Comment: share your vector drawable xml!

Comment: Try android:src="@drawable/ic_cart_plus" instead of app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cart_plus"

Comment: Added vector drawable. Using src instead of srcCompat made no change

Comment: Could you try setting `android:width` and `android:height` to 24dp to see if that's working? Floating Action Buttons are quite restrictive in regard to sizes. Depending on the version you'll find different once.

Comment: If the problem is still keeping add this to build.gradle android {
   defaultConfig {
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
 }

Comment: any of suggested worked. I'm still facing the issue but I found it is related to mercadopago dependency

Answer (score 2):

Set

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
 }
```

in your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to update your dependencies

I got it to work while using those dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0"


<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/drawable_test"
    />
```

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old question, and others might have the same problem, so I add this answer.

As others suggested, add the following dependencies to build.gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'
```

Also as others suggested, add this to build.gradle:

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
 }
```

In the vector, change `android:width` and `android:height` to `android:width="24dp"` and `android:height="24dp"`.

In layout, in `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton`, add `app:fabCustomSize="56dp"` or instead of this, add `app:fabSize="normal"`.

Answer (score 0):

The **[FloatingActionButton](https://material.io/develop/android/components/floating-action-button/)** widget provides a complete implementation of Material Design’s floating action button component.

upgrade your dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

> Using AppCompat and **app:srcCompat** is the most foolproof method of
>   integrating vector drawables into your app.

**Finally**

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_vector"
```

Note - Kindly reduce **width,height** value.

```
   <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="20dp"
    android:height="20dp"
    android:viewportWidth="200"
    android:viewportHeight="200">
```

> Android Studio 1.4 introduced limited compatibility support for vector
>   drawables by generating PNG files at build time. However, the vector
>   drawable and animated vector drawable support Libraries offer both
>   flexibility and broad compatibility — it's a support library, so you
>   can use it with all Android platform versions back to Android 2.1 (API
>   level 7+). To configure your app to use vector support libraries, add
>   the vectorDrawables element to your build.gradle file in the app
>   module.

Use the following code snippet to configure the vectorDrawables element:

```
//For Gradle Plugin 2.0+
 android {
   defaultConfig {
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

u can solve your issue with this idea,

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_new_sale"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_cart_plus"
    android:scaleType="center"/>
```

here u can use android:src insted of app:srcCompat

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me using the following depencencies

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4"
```

try updating these depencencies. I didnt have to do any rescaling. maybe also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52635233/floating-action-button-icon-not-centered-inside) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477028/android-floating-button-icon-is-not-centred) questions as it might be that your drawable is just not centered properly and leaving the circle

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your `srcCompat` to `src`, and that would solve the problem for you.
I am attaching my own FAB code for your ease:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_explore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_16"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_explore_black_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
        app:tint="@color/color_white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```