# Floating action Button is not supporting image?

Tags: android, image, floating-action-button

I have two different images one is supporting in floating action button and another is not. Here is my code

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            app:tint="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/chat"
            app:borderWidth="3dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#fb6d6c"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            app:elevation="8dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="center" />
```

[image: this image is not display]

and another is displaying

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60641115/12478830

Comment: Remove `android:backgroundTint` and use `app:backgroundTint`. Use  `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:src`.Post also your second layout.

Comment: I have tried all these options